# Why does Xdebug quit immediately in NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have recently upgraded to macOs High Sierra and PHP 7.2.  I'm not sure when xdebug stopped working exactly, but now I am experiencing the following behavior:

1. Xdebug starts correctly and waits patiently on the first line of the
   code.
2. Any attempt to play, step into or step over causes the
   debug session to immediately quit and the output window to close.

To resolve this problem, I have uninstalled and reinstalled, PHP 7.2, Xdebug, and NetBeans 8.2.

I have also made changes to the config files attempting to change the port, the idekey, and the other various settings.

### Current Settings

#### Xdebug config (Dumped using `php -i`)

All help is appreciated, here are my current settings:

```
Developer:conf.d jaredclemence$ php -i | grep 'xdebug'
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
IDE Key => netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => netbeans-xdebug => netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => On => On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
Developer:conf.d jaredclemence$
```

#### NetBeans 8.2 Screenshots

[image]

[image]

We leave the index file and arguments blank so that we can use the NetBeans `Debug File` command.

[image]

#### Screenshot of File Used for Debug Session

This file was created to run as a single disconnected test to remove any code complications from the matter.  I am running this using the `Debug File` command, which is possible because I left a lot of the settings blank in the `Run Configuration` settings pictured above.

[image]

### Documented Behavior with Screenshots

**Step 1:** I open the test file.

**Step 2:** I set several breakpoints for test
[image]

**Step 3:** I click ***Debug File***
[image]

**Step 4:** The debug session starts.

**Step 5:** The debugger pauses on line 1 (as requested)
[image]

**Step 6:** Click any debug button: (play, step over, step into)

**Step 7:** The debug session ends. The console adds ***Done*** to signal the end of the session.

[image]

### XDebug Log Output

```
Log opened at 2017-12-21 21:12:44
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000. :-|
W: Creating socket for 'localhost:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.0" protocol_version="1.0" appid="40804" idekey="netbeans-xdebug"><engine version="2.6.0alpha1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2017-12-21 21:12:44

Log opened at 2017-12-21 21:14:17
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000. :-|
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/Core/test-debug.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.0" protocol_version="1.0" appid="41414" idekey="netbeans-debugger"><engine version="2.6.0alpha1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 210 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="210" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 211 -n max_depth -v 3
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="211" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 212 -n max_children -v 30
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="212" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 213 -n max_data -v 2048
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="213" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 214 -t line -s disabled -f file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/Core/php/templates/ElectrocardiogramTemplate.php -n 27
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="214" state="disabled" id="414140001"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 215 -t line -s disabled -f file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/rest.php -n 12
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="215" state="disabled" id="414140002"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 216 -t line -s enabled -f file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/test/Core3/routing/RouteTest.php -n 88
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="216" state="enabled" id="414140003"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 217 -t line -s enabled -f file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/Core/test-debug.php -n 12
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="217" state="enabled" id="414140004"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 218 -t line -s enabled -f file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/Core/test-debug.php -n 17
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="218" state="enabled" id="414140005"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 219 -t line -s enabled -f file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/Core/test-debug.php -n 21
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="219" state="enabled" id="414140006"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 220 -t line -s enabled -f file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/Core/test-debug.php -n 25
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="220" state="enabled" id="414140007"></response>

<- stdout -i 221 -c 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="221" success="1"></response>

<- step_into -i 222
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="222" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/Core/test-debug.php" lineno="3"></xdebug:message></response>

<- eval -i 223 -- JHRoaXMtPnJlbGF0ZWQtPmdldFRhYmxlKCkuJy4nLiR0aGlzLT5zZWNvbmRLZXk=
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="223" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- eval -i 224 -- JHRoaXMtPnBhcmVudC0+Z2V0VGFibGUoKS4nLicuJHRoaXMtPnNlY29uZExvY2FsS2V5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="224" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- eval -i 225 -- cmV0dXJuICR0aGlzLT50aHJvdWdoUGFyZW50LT5nZXRUYWJsZSgpLicuJy4kdGhpcy0+Zmlyc3RLZXk=
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="225" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- eval -i 226 -- JHRoaXMtPmZpcnN0S2V5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="226" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- eval -i 227 -- JHRoaXMtPnRocm91Z2hQYXJlbnQ=
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="227" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- stack_get -i 228
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="228"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/medface/Core/test-debug.php" lineno="0"></stack></response>

<- context_names -i 229
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="229"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

<- eval -i 230 -- JHRoaXMtPnJlbGF0ZWQtPmdldFRhYmxlKCkuJy4nLiR0aGlzLT5zZWNvbmRLZXk=
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="230" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- eval -i 231 -- JHRoaXMtPnBhcmVudC0+Z2V0VGFibGUoKS4nLicuJHRoaXMtPnNlY29uZExvY2FsS2V5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="231" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- eval -i 232 -- cmV0dXJuICR0aGlzLT50aHJvdWdoUGFyZW50LT5nZXRUYWJsZSgpLicuJy4kdGhpcy0+Zmlyc3RLZXk=
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="232" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- eval -i 233 -- JHRoaXMtPmZpcnN0S2V5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="233" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- eval -i 234 -- JHRoaXMtPnRocm91Z2hQYXJlbnQ=
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="234" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

<- context_get -i 235 -c 0
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="235" context="0"><property name="$sum" fullname="$sum" type="uninitialized"></property><property name="$sum2" fullname="$sum2" type="uninitialized"></property><property name="$test" fullname="$test" type="uninitialized"></property></response>

<- context_get -i 236 -c 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="236" context="1"><property name="$_COOKIE" fullname="$_COOKIE" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="30"></property><property name="$_ENV" fullname="$_ENV" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="30"></property><property name="$_FILES" fullname="$_FILES" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="30"></property><property name="$_GET" fullname="$_GET" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="30"></property><property name="$_POST" fullname="$_POST" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="30"></property><property name="$_REQUEST" fullname="$_REQUEST" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="30"></property><property name="$_SERVER" fullname="$_SERVER" type="array" children="1" numchildren="31" page="0" pagesize="30"><property name="PATH" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;PATH&quot;]" type="string" size="29" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3Vzci9iaW46L2JpbjovdXNyL3NiaW46L3NiaW4=]]></property><property name="APP_ICON_39795" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;APP_ICON_39795&quot;]" type="string" size="84" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L0FwcGxpY2F0aW9ucy9OZXRCZWFucy9OZXRCZWFucyA4LjIuYXBwL0NvbnRlbnRzL1Jlc291cmNlcy9OZXRCZWFucy9uYi9uZXRiZWFucy5pY25z]]></property><property name="J2D_PIXMAPS" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;J2D_PIXMAPS&quot;]" type="string" size="6" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[c2hhcmVk]]></property><property name="SHELL" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SHELL&quot;]" type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L2Jpbi9iYXNo]]></property><property name="APP_NAME_39795" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;APP_NAME_39795&quot;]" type="string" size="8" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[TmV0QmVhbnM=]]></property><property name="USER" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;USER&quot;]" type="string" size="13" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[amFyZWRjbGVtZW5jZQ==]]></property><property name="TMPDIR" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;TMPDIR&quot;]" type="string" size="49" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3Zhci9mb2xkZXJzL3N6L3liZnFuMmI5NmQ5Yjl6cnA0cXdfZDZsMDAwMDBnbi9ULw==]]></property><property name="SSH_AUTH_SOCK" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SSH_AUTH_SOCK&quot;]" type="string" size="51" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3ByaXZhdGUvdG1wL2NvbS5hcHBsZS5sYXVuY2hkLjcxZk93QnJ2YWkvTGlzdGVuZXJz]]></property><property name="XPC_FLAGS" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;XPC_FLAGS&quot;]" type="string" size="3" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MHgw]]></property><property name="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;LD_LIBRARY_PATH&quot;]" type="string" size="157" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L0xpYnJhcnkvSmF2YS9KYXZhVmlydHVhbE1hY2hpbmVzL2pkazEuOC4wXzExMS5qZGsvQ29udGVudHMvSG9tZS9qcmUvbGliL2FtZDY0Oi9MaWJyYXJ5L0phdmEvSmF2YVZpcnR1YWxNYWNoaW5lcy9qZGsxLjguMF8xMTEuamRrL0NvbnRlbnRzL0hvbWUvanJlL2xpYi9pMzg2Og==]]></property><property name="__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING&quot;]" type="string" size="13" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MHgxRjU6MHgwOjB4MA==]]></property><property name="Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render&quot;]" type="string" size="48" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3ByaXZhdGUvdG1wL2NvbS5hcHBsZS5sYXVuY2hkLld2QlV3RVVIc3cvUmVuZGVy]]></property><property name="LOGNAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;LOGNAME&quot;]" type="string" size="13" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[amFyZWRjbGVtZW5jZQ==]]></property><property name="XDEBUG_CONFIG" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;XDEBUG_CONFIG&quot;]" type="string" size="24" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aWRla2V5PW5ldGJlYW5zLWRlYnVnZ2Vy]]></property><property name="LC_CTYPE" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;LC_CTYPE&quot;]" type="string" size="5" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[VVRGLTg=]]></property><property name="XPC_SERVICE_NAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;XPC_SERVICE_NAME&quot;]" type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MA==]]></property><property name="PWD" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;PWD&quot;]" type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Lw==]]></property><property name="JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_39795" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_39795&quot;]" type="string" size="17" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[b3JnLm5ldGJlYW5zLk1haW4=]]></property><property name="SHLVL" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SHLVL&quot;]" type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MQ==]]></property><property name="HOME" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HOME&quot;]" type="string" size="20" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L1VzZXJzL2phcmVkY2xlbWVuY2U=]]></property><property name="NB_EXEC_EXTEXECUTION_PROCESS_UUID" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;NB_EXEC_EXTEXECUTION_PROCESS_UUID&quot;]" type="string" size="36" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[YTQ5MDliZDYtOWZmNS00ZTA0LWIzYzAtZjYwYmM1ZTY1YjMz]]></property><property name="_" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;_&quot;]" type="string" size="73" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L0xpYnJhcnkvSmF2YS9KYXZhVmlydHVhbE1hY2hpbmVzL2pkazEuOC4wXzExMS5qZGsvQ29udGVudHMvSG9tZS9iaW4vamF2YQ==]]></property><property name="PHP_SELF" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;PHP_SELF&quot;]" type="string" size="56" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L0xpYnJhcnkvV2ViU2VydmVyL0RvY3VtZW50cy9tZWRmYWNlL0NvcmUvdGVzdC1kZWJ1Zy5waHA=]]></property><property name="SCRIPT_NAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SCRIPT_NAME&quot;]" type="string" size="56" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L0xpYnJhcnkvV2ViU2VydmVyL0RvY3VtZW50cy9tZWRmYWNlL0NvcmUvdGVzdC1kZWJ1Zy5waHA=]]></property><property name="SCRIPT_FILENAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SCRIPT_FILENAME&quot;]" type="string" size="56" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L0xpYnJhcnkvV2ViU2VydmVyL0RvY3VtZW50cy9tZWRmYWNlL0NvcmUvdGVzdC1kZWJ1Zy5waHA=]]></property><property name="PATH_TRANSLATED" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;PATH_TRANSLATED&quot;]" type="string" size="56" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L0xpYnJhcnkvV2ViU2VydmVyL0RvY3VtZW50cy9tZWRmYWNlL0NvcmUvdGVzdC1kZWJ1Zy5waHA=]]></property><property name="DOCUMENT_ROOT" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;DOCUMENT_ROOT&quot;]" type="string" size="0" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[]]></property><property name="REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT&quot;]" type="float"><![CDATA[1513890857.0138]]></property><property name="REQUEST_TIME" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;REQUEST_TIME&quot;]" type="int"><![CDATA[1513890857]]></property><property name="argv" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;argv&quot;]" type="array" children="1" numchildren="1" page="0" pagesize="30"><property name="0" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;argv&quot;][0]" type="string" size="56" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L0xpYnJhcnkvV2ViU2VydmVyL0RvY3VtZW50cy9tZWRmYWNlL0NvcmUvdGVzdC1kZWJ1Zy5waHA=]]></property></property></property></response>

<- context_get -i 237 -c 2
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="237" context="2"></response>

<- run -i 238
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="238" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2017-12-21 21:14:25
```

Comment: Check what xdebug log has to say about it.

Comment: I added the xdebug log output. Nothing jumpts out at me as being an error, but this is also the first time I am reading an xdebug log file.

Comment: It notes that the remote address (localhost?) is not found, but then the next line says connected with client.  This warning might be important, but the fact that it successfully connects with client suggests that it is not a problem.  Thoughts?

Comment: **1)** *"It notes that the remote address (localhost?) is not found"* Where? It doe snot say that at all -- try reading it again. **2)** *"Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000" -- this means that your `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` fails .. which is correct as it does nothing for CLI (makes sense for web requests only). **3)** You have 2 debug session sin your log: 1st finished without properly starting -- typical response if you have php-fpm running locally (which uses the same TCP 9000 port by default -- that's why better use 9001 or so for xdebug)

Comment: At the same time the `fileuri="dbgp://stdin"` for the first session looks odd to me (never seen it). But I doubt it affects anything. **4)** It feels like your log was altered -- looks like quite a few lines from the middle of the log are missing. **5)** Other than that it looks OK in general (nothing super obviously wrong to me at first glance). Maybe it's because of the version? PHP 7.2 and xdebug 2.6.alpha... I say -- try with PHP 7.1 and xdebug 2.5.x -- they are more stable versions.

Comment: I updated the xdebug INI file to create this log. I then used a utility for macOS called xdebug-toggle, which restarts the PHP services and any attached services to reload xdebug in an on or off state.  The first session is the record that was created when I ran "xdebug-toggle on" from the command line, which is probably why the "dbgp://stdin" appears as the fileuri.

Comment: I have tried this both with and without the remote_connect_back=1.... Both seem to have the same result.

Comment: With respect to the log being altered. I can assert that this was a fresh log created just for this page. No alteration has been performed... perhaps any gaps might be an indication of an underlying problem that is related?

Comment: *"perhaps any gaps might be an indication of an underlying problem that is related"* Unlikely - possibly NetBeans works this way (starts command IDs from much higher number -- I'm just comparing to what I see here in PhpStorm). In any case, from what I can say from the log: xdebug breaks at first non-empty lines, breakpoints got set, file paths matching. No idea why it does not break after you hit "Run" again to resume program execution.

Comment: Can you please share your debug test script (whole file -- share via Google Drive or alike) - maybe something wrong there. Otherwise -- make even simpler script -- like `$a = 1; $b = 2; $c = $a + $b; echo $c;` -- one instruction per line.

Comment: I created a simpler script. It has the same problem.  You can download it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LYm3yT3M3pAPHyn2RJt8YLJV5BSQ0SdL

Comment: If simpler script has the same problem ... then it's not needed. I thought maybe original one has some special about it. In such case -- I'm out of ideas (expect trying it in older PHP/xdebug) .. or another IDE (just to test it).